# Text in status bar like Mailbox

Tags: iphone

I've looked around at ways in the past to show short messages/text in the Status Bar and have always come to the conclusion that it isn't really possible, or not possible reliably - but the Mailbox app uses it extensively and it seems to work really well.

Does anyone know of a way or a framework or something that can present text in the status bar like that? Is this a relatively new development? I found MTStatusBarOverlay but that looks like it hasn't been touched in almost a year which makes me nervous. Any others that are good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably you are looking for http://bit.ly/WXpUEg
FDStatusBarNotifierView looks good

Comment: Cool, that does look good and is under development it looks. Thanks!